# ElasticSearch more_like_this with restricted result set

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity, morelikethis

I want to run a `more_like_this` query, but only get the top results within a specific set of documents, so I would provide the IDs of these documents.  Is there any way to do this? [Docs indicate no.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-mlt-query.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html?q=filtered%20query) and use the [id filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-ids-filter.html) to specify the set of documents you want the `more_like_this` query to work on

Example:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "more_like_this": {
               "fields": [
                  "ticker.whitespace"
               ],
               "like_text": "WFC",
               "min_term_freq": 1,
               "max_query_terms": 12
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "ids": {
               "values": [
                  "7667"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```